# Denied permission by Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I work with Firebase and for my Firestore Database I created the rules:

```js
// Budgets
match /budgets/{budget} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow update, delete, create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId;
}
```

Somehow Firebase allows me to create a budget. But unfortunately when I try to delete created budget I receive error:

> FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Code for deleting a budget:

```js
async function deleteBudget({ id }) {
    try {
        const budgetToDeleteQuery = query(collection(db, 'budgets'), where('id', '==', id), where('userId', '==', currentUser?.uid));
        const budgetToDeleteData = await getDocs(budgetToDeleteQuery);
        const budgetToDelete = doc(db, 'budgets', budgetToDeleteData.docs[0].id);
        await deleteDoc(budgetToDelete);
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
    // setBudgets(prevState => prevState.filter(item => item.id !== id));
}
```

[image]
Can anyone tell me what's the problem here?

Comment: Please show the full code for deleting a budget.

Comment: added code + pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `delete`, use `resource` because it is the document before the operation takes place, which in this case is the budget you want to delete.

Check the code below.

```
 // Budgets
 match /budgets/{budget} {
       allow read: if request.auth != null;
       allow update, create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId;
       allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use

```
allow write:
```

instead of

```
allow update, delete, create:
```

Comment: Done. The same message pops up "FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.". Still can create a budget but still cant delete one.